# Sending strings from a list over a socket to be displayed in real time

Tags: python, python-3.x

My list contains IP addresses and port numbers of connected clients to my program.  The admin threads role is to send each currently connected clients IP address and port number to an admin client in this string format - eg '172.0.0.1 1234'.  Could I have some advise on how to send each each address so that it only shows currently connected addresses and port numbers on the admin client program.

addressList is a global variable list

Here is my code-

**Server**

```
import threading
import socket
import math
import random
import ssl

addressList = []

def within(guess,goal,n):
    absValue = abs(guess - goal)
    if absValue <= n:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def HandleAdmin(adminSocket,):
    global addressList

    (c,a) = adminSocket.accept()
    ts = ssl.wrap_socket(c, certfile="5cc515_server.crt",
                             keyfile="5cc515_server.key",
                             server_side=True,
                             cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                             ca_certs="5cc515-root-ca.cer")

    if ts.recv(80).decode() == 'Hello\r\n':
        ts.send('Admin-Greetings\r\n'.encode()) 

    if ts.recv(80).decode() == 'Who\r\n':
        for addr in addressList:
            ts.send(addr).encode()
    ts.close()
    return

def HandleClient(c,a):
    global addressList
    address, port = a
    address = str(address) + ' ' + str(port)
    addressList.append(address) 

    scoreCount = 0
    guess = 0
    if(c.recv(80).decode()) == 'Hello\r\n':
        c.send('Greetings\r\n'.encode())

        goal = random.randrange(1,21)

        while guess!= goal:
            guess =c.recv(80).decode()
            guess = int(guess[7:len(guess)-2])

            if guess == goal:
                c.send('Correct\r\n'.encode())
            elif within(guess, goal, 2) == True:
                c.send('Close\r\n'.encode())
            else:
                c.send('Far\r\n'.encode())
    c.close()
    return

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.bind(("127.0.0.1",4000))
clientSocket.listen(5)

adminSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
adminSocket.bind(("127.0.0.1",4001))
adminSocket.listen(5)

handleAdminThread = threading.Thread(target = HandleAdmin,
                                            args = (adminSocket,))
handleAdminThread.start()

while True:
    (c,a) = clientSocket.accept()
    clientThread = threading.Thread(target = HandleClient, args = (c,a))
    clientThread.start()
```

**Admin Client**

```
import ssl
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ts = ssl.wrap_socket(s, certfile="100298750.crt",
                        keyfile="100298750.key",
                        ca_certs="5cc515-root-ca.cer")

ts.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4001))

ts.send("Hello\r\n".encode())

addressList = []

if ts.recv(80).decode() == "Admin-Greetings\r\n":

    print("The players currently playing are:\n\n")
    ts.send("Who\r\n".encode())

    while True:
        print(ts.recv(80).decode())
```

Comment: Any suggestion is better than no suggestion, am I right? xD
So I don't know much about sockets and whatnot, so I'm sorry if my suggestion is useless. But here it is: How about, when they disconnect, so right before the program terminates for them, you let it send the admin something like "127.0.0.1 1234 quit."

Comment: I'd rather any connections just dissapear off of the screen.  So every time there is a new connection or a connection is dropped, it sends a refreshed iteration of what is in the list.  I only started learning python 2 months ago so my skills are less than basic

Comment: Ehm does your code at the moment actually work? Because if so, I don't even see how :P

Comment: Maybe I should replace with the whole code.  The actual game works

Comment: Yes please. That should help me quite a bit

Comment: I just didn't want people to get carried away and change the whole code.  A simple solution would be better as I have a spec to adhere to

Comment: Obviously there is another player client script but that works fine and isn't needed

Comment: I've seriously been thinking ever since you posted and I have no idea. I looked it up on several sites and it seems like you'll have to check the ipconfig every couple seconds, which is really inefficient in my opinion. So I'm sorry bro, I can't help you do it the way you want it.

Comment: no problem. Cheers dude.  Does programming ever get easier?

Comment: Oh no never mind I think I got it now!

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunatly I still have a problem sending and recieving the addresses

Answer (score 0):

In your HandleClient function, c.close() means the client has disconnected.
So, to let your admin know they did, you have to remove that address from the 'addressList' (since when you send "Who\r\n" your addressList list is referred to).

So, after c.close() you should write:

```
addressList.remove(address)
```